# upload attachment to SharePoint List Item using REST API from Java client

Tags: java, rest, http, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Following Java code is an example for uploading a file attachment to the SharePoint 2013 list item.

```
    String uploadquery =siteurl+ _api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='File1.txt')";

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uploadquery);
    httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    httppost.addHeader("X-RequestDigest", FormDigestValue);
    httppost.addHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "PUT");
    httppost.addHeader("If-Match", "*");

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("This is a Body");
    httppost.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost, localContext);
```

It creates the file with the content.But it returns the following error in the response.

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The type SP.File does not support HTTP PATCH method."}}}
```

what causes this issue?

in Above code,I upload simple text content.But How to upload other file types such as excel/ppt or images to sharepoint list item ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Working with folders and files with REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553(v=office.15).aspx#FileAttachments) the following properties have to be specified for creating file attachment to a list item:

- `POST` method for HTTP request
- `X-RequestDigest` header with `FormDigest` value
- HTTP request `body` and `content length`

Pseudo example:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(item id)/AttachmentFiles/ add(FileName='file name')
method: POST
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    body: "Contents of file."
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-length:length of post body
```

### C# example

The following C# example demonstrates how to upload create file attachment to a list item using [Network API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net(v=vs.110).aspx) into SharePoint Online (SPO):

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath);
var requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('{1}')/items({2})/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='{3}')", webUrl, listTitle, itemId,fileName);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
request.Credentials = credentials;  //SharePointOnlineCredentials object 
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");

request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", requestDigest);

var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFilePath);
request.ContentLength = fileContent.Length;
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I believe with minimal effort it could be converted into Java version.

Comment: What is requestDigest?

Comment: The Request digest can be obtained from yoursite/_api/context.
i guess you have to make another http request to the above api, get the digest and send it with the post request

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following URL and related code below worked for me

> https://[your_domain].sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/[FolderName]')/Files/Add(url='"
>   + [FileName] + "',overwrite=true)

```
public String putRecordInSharePoint(File file) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    /* Token variable declaration */
    String token = getSharePointAccessToken();
    /* Null or fail check */
    if (!token.equalsIgnoreCase(RcConstants.OAUTH_FAIL_MESSAGE))
    {
        /* Upload path and file name declaration */
        String Url_parameter = "Add(url='" + file.getName() + "',overwrite=true)";
        String url = RcConstants.UPLOAD_FOLDER_URL + Url_parameter;


        /* Building URL */
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        post.setHeader("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        /* Declaring File Entity */
        post.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));

        /* Executing the post request */
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        logger.debug("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK.value()
                || response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.ACCEPTED.value())
        {
            /* Returning Success Message */
            return RcConstants.UPLOAD_SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Returning Failure Message */
            return RcConstants.UPLOAD_FAIL_MESSAGE;
        }
    }
    return token;
}
```

Comment: I am able to do get requests but can you give me proper sample that i can use for [FileName] . I am getting error 403 (only for upload call) with response System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser....' Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the following examples from POC feel free to look at them.
https://github.com/nikhiln64/Java-REST-API-Projects/tree/master/SharePoint-REST-API-Framework/src/main/java/com/sharepoint/connect

Comment: Use any pdf/doc/other type of files and you have to change the file name as follows:
/Files/Add(url='file1.pdf', overwrite=true)
Try with Postman initially then eventually you will figure out.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try it now :)